# Use page attribute in include statement jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I have a jekyll page where I have the the two folders: `products` `_products/product_name`

and I have a product page md file containg this:

```
---
title: product_title
subtitle: subtilte
layout: product
description: long description
product_icon: product_image_path
---
```

And this simple layout:

```
---
layout: default
---
<!-- Main -->
<div id="main">
  <div id="content" class="container">
    <header id="product_header">
      <div class="half_left center">
        <img id="product_icon" src="/assets/{{ page.product_icon }}" alt="">
    <h2 id="product_title">{{ page.title }}</h2>
        <h3 id="product_subtitle">{{page.subtitle}}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="half_right center">
        {% markdown _products/page.title/short.md %}
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>

    </header>
        {{content}}
  </div>
</div>
```

However in: `{% markdown _products/page.title/short.md %}` I seem unable to capture the page title, how can I do this?

My markdown tag:

```
# From: http://wolfslittlestore.be/2013/10/rendering-markdown-in-jekyll/
=begin
  Jekyll tag to include Markdown text from _includes directory preprocessing with Liquid.
  Usage:
    {% markdown <filename> %}
  Dependency:
    - kramdown
=end
module Jekyll
  class MarkdownTag < Liquid::Tag
    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
      @text = text.strip
    end
    require "kramdown"
    def render(context)
      tmpl = File.read File.join Dir.pwd, "", @text
      site = context.registers[:site]
      tmpl = (Liquid::Template.parse tmpl).render site.site_payload
      html = Kramdown::Document.new(tmpl).to_html
    end
  end
end
Liquid::Template.register_tag('markdown', Jekyll::MarkdownTag)
```

Can someone tell me how I capture the page.title in the `{% markdown _products/page.title/short.md %}` I get this error: `Liquid Exception: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/tools/git/pagename.github.io/_products/page.title/short in _layouts/product.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a different a build in solution with jekyll, such that I did not neeed a plugin in

let us say you have markdown file `john.md` in path `markdown_files` we can then we can do the following:

```
{% capture john %}
    {% include_relative markdown_files/john.md %}
{% endcapture %}
```

Then where we want to input the text of `john.md` now captured in `john` we can put this `{{ john | markdownify }}`

It is not a sleek an not a one liner, but it works. Depending on your setup you can use `include` instead of `include_relative`

Hope it can help someone else, and thank to the Jekyll IRC community for helping me find a solution.